# Combining lambdas in Java?

Tags: java, function, lambda, dry

I have a lambda

```
(a, b) -> {
  a.doSomething();
  a.doAnotherThing();
  return b.doSomething();
}
```

Right now, this just gets used as a parameter in a single method. However, I would also like to create a similar lambda

```
(a) -> {
  a.doSomething();
  a.doAnotherThing();
  return a
}
```

Is there some way I could reuse my code? Something like

```
(a, b) -> {
  partial(a)
  return b.doSomething();
}

(a) -> {
  partial(a)
  return a;
}
```

Comment: Sure.  What's stopping you?

Comment: ... I don't know how? I don't know what the correct code would look like

Comment: It'd look exactly like what you've already suggested.  Just write a method `partial(a)`.

Comment: If you rework your methods on `a` to be functions, have a look a `Function.andThen()` and/or `Function.compose()`

Comment: @Bohemian, neither `andThen` nor `compose` apply here because `a.doSomething()` followed by `a.doAnotherThing()` is f(a),g(a), not g(f(a)) or f(g(a))

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to call a lambda from another lambda?

You could give them a name and use them like any other function

```
Function<X,Y> partial = (a) -> {
    a.doSomething();
    a.doAnotherThing();
    return a;
}

BiFunction<X,Y,Z> lam = (a, b) -> {
  partial.apply(a);
  return b.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Type of `lam` should be `BiFunction<X, Y, Z>`.

Comment: `partial(a)` -> `partial.apply(a)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your use of `partial` here is not referring to the functional programming concept of partial functions.

Looking at your examples, the operations on `a` taken together are just a Consumer since they don't return any values. Your reusable lambda could be declared like this:

```
Consumer<A> partial = a -> {
    a.doSomething();
    a.doAnotherThing();
}
```

To compose a function that first calls a consumer, you could keep this helper handy:

```
static <T,U,R> BiFunction<T,U,R> acceptAndThen(Consumer<T> c, Function<U,R> f){
    return (t,u) -> {
        c.accept(t);
        return f.apply(u);
    };
}
```

which you could use to compose a function equivalent to your original function like this (I don't know `b.doSomething()`'s return type, I'll assume C):

```
BiFunction<A,B,C> f1 = acceptAndThen(partial, B::doSomething); // equivalent to (a, b) -> { partial.accept(a); return b.doSomething(); }
```

Your second example, which shows how you might reuse `partial` in a different way, would benefit from another helper that converts a `Consumer<T>` to a `Function<T,T>` by returning the `T` that the `Consumer<T>` operated on:

```
static <T> Function<T,T> returnSelf(Consumer<T> consumer){
    return t -> {
        consumer.accept(t);
        return t;
    };
}
```

So you could create your second example like this:

```
Function<A,A> f2 = returnSelf(partial); // equivalent to (a) -> { partial.accept(a); return a; }
```

These compositions are not in the standard library, but you'll find that interfaces like `Consumer` and `Function` have some built-in functions for composing existing functional types into new ones.  For instance, `Consumer` has a function, `andThen` that can chain consumers to be called in sequence.  Using that your partial might have looked like

```
Consumer<A> partial = ((Consumer<A>) A::doSomething).andThen(A::doAnotherThing);
```